# Хранить комментария в базе данных

Tags: база-данных, комментарии

Как хранить комментария в базе данных? Моя таблица коммментарии такого: <br/>
<pre >id, text, id_user, idPost </pre> <br/>
Но еще есть ответь к комментарие и к одному комментарие можеть быть несколько ответный комментарии. Тогда как должно выгледет таблица комментарии?

Answer (score 1):

Тогда Вам нужна древовидная структура. Просто у каждого комментария должен быть ещё id родительского комментария. И всех делов.